# SQL query for finding tables containing a column in my schema

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anybody tell me SQL query to return all the tables in my schema which have the column name "IS_REVIEW_APPEALS" ?

I am using Oracle database.

Thanks a lot,

Bhushan

Comment: I would change the question to "SQL query for finding tables/views containing a column in my schema"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM user_tab_cols
 WHERE column_name = 'IS_REVIEW_APPEALS'
```

Comment: Might want to query ALL_TAB_COLS if you aren't the owner of the schema.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells - True.  But the question specifically says "in my schema".

Comment: This also searches in the VIEWS, which is great!

Answer (score 3):

See below query for how to get all columns with the given name for a specific schema in Oracle:

```
SELECT 
    t.owner AS schema_name,
    t.table_name, 
    c.column_name
FROM sys.all_tables t 
    INNER JOIN sys.all_tab_columns c ON t.table_name = c.table_name
WHERE LOWER(t.owner) = LOWER('MySchemaNameHere')
    AND LOWER(c.column_name) LIKE LOWER('%MyColumnNameHere%')
ORDER BY t.owner, t.table_name, c.column_name;
```